# Compare integer to value inputted in TextView

Tags: android

Lets say I set two variables such as fnum=5, snum=6 and I set answer=fnum + snum, is there

Comment: What type of variable is `answer1`?

Answer (score 1):

In your case `answer1` is generic integer type
You're probably confusing it with `EditText` or `TextView` as there is no `getText()` method for it.

You can either convert answer to string: `Integer.toString(answer1)`
and then compare it to string from EditText

Or either by parsing EditText string value to integer (which would I do)

```
int userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
int realAnswer = snum + fnum;

if ( realAnswer == userAnswer ) {
 // hey Tim, he can do math
}
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting answer1 to a String have you tried parsing the user input to a numerical value(int, or float depending on your implementation) and then using a numerical comparison?  That way you arent trying to compare a string value(which could have extra white-space etc)

Comment: ive tried this but shows an error at getText                         if (answer ==(Integer.parseInt(answer1.getText().toString())))

Comment: shouldnt it be answer1 == Integer.parseInt(answer.getText().toString()))

Comment: You are setting answer1 to an int above and then trying to call getText() on that int value which you cannot do, I think you have switched around answer and answer1(maybe use names like userAnswer and  correctAnswer)